# Как вставить в php обработчик, чтобы значения передавались по radio

Tags: php

Есть код html, точнее обычная кнопка type="radio", но по ней ничего не происходит.

**Эти поля нормально передает**

```
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="Заказ обратного звонка"readonly>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя" required>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required>
<input type="text" name="calltime" placeholder="Удобное время для звонка" required>
```

**По радио не посылает**

```
<label><input type="radio" name="main-billiard"><span class="number-ft">12 фут &mdash; </span><span class="old-price">0 р.</span>&nbsp;<span class="curr-price">0 руб.</span></label>
```

**Обработчик который не хочет**

*Как вставить в этот php обработчик код, чтобы выбранное значение передавались по radio?*

```
<?
$tag = @ trim ($_POST['tag']);
$name = @ trim ($_POST['name']);
$contact = @ trim ($_POST['phone']);
$calltime = @ trim ($_POST['calltime']);
$email = @ trim ($_POST['email']);

# проверка, переданы ли все данные
if (! $name or ! $contact) exit ('Необходимо заполнить все поля, вернитесь');
# отправка данных на мыло админу
mail ("admin@site.ru",
      "Сообщение с сайта ($tag)",
      "Имя клиента: $name\nКонтактный телефон: $contact\nEmail: $email \nУдобное время для звонка: $calltime",
"Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8");
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
?>
```

**Пробовала делать по аналогии, данные не выводятся**

```
<?
$tag = @ trim ($_POST['tag']);
$name = @ trim ($_POST['name']);
$contact = @ trim ($_POST['phone']);
$email = @ trim ($_POST['email']);
$billiard = @ trim ($_POST['main-billiard']);
# проверка, переданы ли все данные
if (! $name or ! $contact) exit ('Необходимо заполнить все поля, вернитесь');
# отправка данных на мыло админу
mail ("admin@site.ru",
      "Сообщение с сайта ($tag)",
      "Имя клиента: $name\nКонтактный телефон: $contact\nEmail: $email \n$billiard",
"Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8");
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
?>
```

**Непонятный скрип**

*не работает, наверное дело в непонятном для меня скрипте который отправляет на обработчик send.php*
И плюс тут валидация дурацкая с подсветкой полей, не знаю как ее вырезать, чтобы оставить работать только в html required

```
function number_format(_number, _cfg){
      function obj_merge(obj_first, obj_second){
        var obj_return = {};
        for (key in obj_first){
          if (typeof obj_second[key] !== 'undefined') obj_return[key] = obj_second[key];
          else obj_return[key] = obj_first[key];
          }
        return obj_return;
      }
      function thousands_sep(_num, _sep){
        if (_num.length <= 3) return _num;
        var _count = _num.length;
        var _num_parser = '';
        var _count_digits = 0;
        for (var _p = (_count - 1); _p >= 0; _p--){
          var _num_digit = _num.substr(_p, 1);
          if (_count_digits % 3 == 0 && _count_digits != 0 && !isNaN(parseFloat(_num_digit))) _num_parser = _sep + _num_parser;
          _num_parser = _num_digit + _num_parser;
          _count_digits++;
          }
        return _num_parser;
      }
      if (typeof _number !== 'number'){
        _number = parseFloat(_number);
        if (isNaN(_number)) return false;
      }
      var _cfg_default = {before: '', after: '', decimals: 2, dec_point: '.', thousands_sep: ','};
      if (_cfg && typeof _cfg === 'object'){
        _cfg = obj_merge(_cfg_default, _cfg);
      }
      else _cfg = _cfg_default;
      _number = _number.toFixed(_cfg.decimals);
      if(_number.indexOf('.') != -1){
        var _number_arr = _number.split('.');
        var _number = thousands_sep(_number_arr[0], _cfg.thousands_sep) + _cfg.dec_point + _number_arr[1];
      }
      else var _number = thousands_sep(_number, _cfg.thousands_sep);
      return _cfg.before + _number + _cfg.after;
    }

    $(function() {
        $('a[rel=popup]').leanModal({closeButton:'.close-popup'});

        $('.red-btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            val = {};
            $('.error-input').removeClass('error-input');
            err = false;
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('type')=='radio') {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) val['type'] = $(this).val();
                }
                else {
                    if ($(this).val()=='') {
                        err = true;
                        $(this).addClass('error-input');
                    } else
                        val[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            if (err) return;
            $.post("send.php",val);
            $('#lean_overlay').click();
            $('#ok-btn').click();
        });
    });
```

Comment: $_POST['main-billiard'] ?

Comment: Пробовала так, ничего не выводит.

Comment: а ну да....

     <input type="radio" value="1" name="main-billiard"/>

когда пункт один лучше вообще использовать checkbox...

Comment: пунктов несколько точнее 2, просто в примере выложила один.

Comment: ну ко всем value

Comment: да никак, скорей всего блокирует скриптом, который между обработчиком стоит. Ну да ладно( благодарю и за то, поинт поставить не могу, не предусмотренно тут для комментариев ставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте у `radio` поставить  атрибут `value="1"`, а в обработчике

`if ($billiard == 1) { mail...}`

Comment: Нет, скорей всего дело в скрипте который идет до обработчика, этот скрипт все блокирует, не дает использовать валидацию по required, и проверяет все поля на заполнение, то есть если я в обработчике (Либо в html ) обозначу некоторые поля необязательными, то он все равно будет требовать все значения.

Comment: Добавила вверху непонятный скрипт, если разбираетесь помогите вырезать ненужное, валидацию